# Google Analytics uses gif get request why not post request?

Tags: http-post, httprequest, google-analytics-api, http-get, web-analytics

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/) uses `Get Request` for [.gif image](http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif) to server

`http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4&utmn=769876874&utmhn=example.com&utmcs=ISO-8859-1&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=...`

We can observer that all parameters are sent in this `Get Request` and the requested image is no where found useful ([Its just 1px by 1px Image](http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif))

**Known Information:** *If requesting query string is large then Google are going for `Post Request`.*

Now the question is why not `Post Request` always irrespective of the query string is large or not.

Being data sent via `Get Request` its leads to security issue. Since, the parameters will be stored in browser history or in web server logs in case of `Get Request`.

Could someone give any supportive reasons why [Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/) is depending on both the things?

Comment: "Being data send via get request its leads to security issue." Why? If you mean written to proxy logs then couldn't a malicious proxy operator capture the POST body too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Because GET requests is what you use for retrieving information that does not alter stuff.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Safe_methods)

Please note that the use of POST has quite some downsides, the browser usually warns against reloading a resource requested via POST (to prevent double data-entry), POST requests are not cached (which is why some analytics misuse it), proxied etc.

If you want to retrieve a LOT of data using a URL (advice: rethink if there might be a better option), then it's necessary to use post, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29):

> There are times when HTTP GET is less suitable even for data retrieval. An example of this is when a great deal of data would need to be specified in the URL. Browsers and web servers can have limits on the length of the URL that they will handle without truncation or error. Percent-encoding of reserved characters in URLs and query strings can significantly increase their length, and while Apache HTTP Server can handle up to 4,000 characters in a URL, Microsoft Internet Explorer is limited to 2048 characters in any URL. Equally, HTTP GET should not be used where sensitive information, such as user names and passwords have to be submitted along with other data for the request to complete. In these cases, even if HTTPS is used to encrypt the message body, data in the URL will be passed in clear text and many servers, proxies, and browsers will log the full URL in a way where it might be visible to third parties. In these cases, HTTP POST should be used.

Comment: Not so clear. Consider if we are requesting image and we will be altering stuff on the page right, to display the retrieved information about the image?  I appreciate the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Safe_methods) provided. It will be more helpful if you can brief it..

Comment: If you use the fact that an image is loaded to alter data on the server, then yes, it is perfectly valid to use POST.

Comment: In this case you are specifically creating new information, tracking information on the server.  You don't really care about the image, it's just a means to avoid http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

Answer (score 1):

A POST request would require an ajax call and it wouldn't work because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.  But images can easily be cross-site, so they just need to add an img tag to the DOM with the required url and the browser will load it, sending the needed information to their servers for tracking.

Comment: But it would be easy for Google to add wildcard CORS headers to their image servers to make the cross-site stuff work for POSTs.

Comment: The problem is that you have to add it to the server where the request originates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#How_CORS_works).  The browser says "I'm only going to allow requests to this site or sites this site tells me they trust." It's impractical for them to ask all domains that want to use their tracking to add a CORS header (most users don't have access or knowledge to do this.)

Comment: I think it works the other way, so extra headers are just needed on Google's end. Your link says "Note that in the CORS architecture, the ACAO header is being set by the external web service (bar.com), not the original web application server (foo.com)."

Comment: Seems like you are right.  I misunderstood.  But if you look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors it seems that traditionally not all the browsers supported it.  With a image pixel, everyone would support it.